# Navigation when on the command line

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to jump to the front or end of the command-line, what other things can you do?

Is it possible to delete the entire line?  Or to the next or pervious word in the line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some useful commands

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>: Beginning of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>: End of line
- <kbd>↑</kbd>: Previous command
- <kbd>↓</kbd>: Next command
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>: Cancel command
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>: Forward one word
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>: Backward one word
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>: Delete current character
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>: Delete the last word
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: Swap current character with the previous character
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>: Cut everything after the cursor
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>: Cut everything before the cursor
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>: Paste the last cut text
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>: Undo
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>: Stop writing output to the screen
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>: Start writing output to the screen
- <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>: Clear the screen

Comment: nice, is there a cut everything before the cursor?

Comment: @Blankman Not that I know of. I tried out a bunch of possibilities but nothing seems to do it. Odd that they wouldn't have it.

Comment: Ctrl-U cuts everything before the cursor.  You can find the full list of keybindings in the [bash manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc27), several pages down (search for "Readline Command Names").

Comment: @MariusGedminas Weird, I could have sworn I tried that. I've updated by answer. Thanks for your help.